# how to make a class for method to work with uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am thinking that how can I make a class for twitter or facebook or anything. So just I import that class to my project and it start working with one code. For example. If I use twitter framework then I have to write its functions. I just want to make a class of that funcation which will work on my all future projects by just importing it.
example:

Any class or anything:

```
-(void)shareOnTwitter:(NSString *)text withUrl:(NSURL *)url withImage:(UIImage *)image
{
   // ALL TWITTER Code HERE;
}
```

And in my Main viewController of any project:

```
- (IBAction)socialBtn:(id)sender
{
  [self shareOnTwitter:@"This is Text" withUrl:nil withImage:nil];
}
```

**UPDATE: Just tried Category way but no response return, any idea where I am wrong?:**

**UIViewController+CustomMethods.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface UIViewController (CustomMethods)

-(void)shareOnTwitter:(NSString *)text withUrl:(NSURL *)url withImage:(UIImage *)image;

@end
```

**UIViewController+CustomMethods.m**

```
#import "UIViewController+CustomMethods.h"

@implementation UIViewController (CustomMethods)

-(void)shareOnTwitter:(NSString *)text withUrl:(NSURL *)url withImage:(UIImage *)image {

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {

        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        [tweetSheet setInitialText:text];
        [tweetSheet addImage:image];
        [tweetSheet addURL:url];

        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                  message:@"You can't Post a Status right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

}
@end
```

**mainViewController:**

```
NSString *title = [webViewOutlet stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
            NSURL *url = [[webViewOutlet request] URL];

            [self shareOnTwitter:title withUrl:url withImage:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks every one.. Specially for Chris Loonam, learned how to make delegate methods....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is an instance where you can use an Objective-C feature called "Categories". A category is an extension to an already established class. For example, we can make a category for UIViewController which will add new methods to ALL UIViewController classes.

To do this, we do the following:

Make a .h file declaring prototypes:

```
@interface UIViewController (CategoryName) // EG. (Twitter)
// PROTOTYPES... EG:
-(void)shareOnTwitter:(NSString *)text withUrl:(NSURL *)url withImage:(UIImage *)image;
@end
```

And the corresponding .m file that implements them:

```
@implementation UIViewController (CategoryName)
// IMPLEMENTATIONS... EG:
-(void)shareOnTwitter:(NSString *)text withUrl:(NSURL *)url withImage:(UIImage *)image {
    // Code...
}
@end
```

(Note that when you declare a new file in XCode, it has a "Category" template that you can use.)

Now, whenever you import your .h file, UIViewController as a class will contain the methods you extended it with!

[Here's](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/objective-c-categories/) a tutorial on categories that I found with a quick google search.

Comment: Thanks.. I used NSString Category, and I pretty works for me... Now What Category should I use for this...? UIView or UIViewController...??? +1 for tutorial..

Comment: In your question, you expressed that you wanted to add that method to the UIViewController class. The sample code I wrote shows a category of UIViewController. What did you use an NSString Category for?

Comment: NSString for checking if a string contains a specified string. or for cutting any given text from string. and many more... thanks I will try uiviewcontroller as well...

Answer (score 2):

Create your **Class** of `NSObject` such like,

```
@interface YourClassName : NSObject
.
.
. // put all methods and ivar..etc that your need. (in Proper way)
.
.
```

and put all method in it (*body of method in `.m file`*)

And just `#import "YourClassName.h"` where you want to **inherit** it.

and you access **all Functions** that are put in `YourClassName` class.

Comment: which delegate method ?? yes custom delegate of YourClassName class it  works :)

Comment: No not Custom... like this one - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)mailController didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    NSString *msg1;

Comment: yes add relavent framework and also add this method in .h file and put body in .m file then you can access it :)

Comment: I tried NSObject.. But getting this error "no visible interface..." on this line... [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil]

Answer (score 1):

to make a delegate you would add this above the interface declaration in `YourTwitterClass.h`

```
@protocol YourTwitterDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)delegteMethod;
@end
```

You would do something like this by subclassing `NSObject`

```
//In YourTwitterClass.h
//Twitter framework(needed but I don't know the name)
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourTwitterClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) id<YourTwitterDelegate> delegate;    
-(void)shareOnTwitter:(NSString *)text withUrl:(NSURL *)url withImage:(UIImage *)image delegate:(id<YourTwitterDelegate>)del;

@end


//in YourTwitterClass.m
@implementation YourTwitterClass
-(void)shareOnTwitter:(NSString *)text withUrl:(NSURL *)url withImage:(UIImage *)image delegate:(id<YourTwitterDelegate>)del{
_delegate = del;
[_delegate delegateMethod];//calls the delegate method
//do twitter stuff
}
```

and then in your view controller

```
//import "YourTwitterClass.h"

- (IBAction)socialBtn:(id)sender
{
YourTwitterClass *t = [[YourTwitterClass alloc] init];
[t shareOnTwitter:@"This is Text" withUrl:nil withImage:nil];
}
//and the delegate method
-(void)delegateMethod{
NSLog(@"This is a delegate method!);
}
```

In your `ViewController.h` file you also have to add this to the interface declaration

**EDIT**
if you want to add a delegate for say, a mail composer, add the delegate for that class

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
//or
@interface YourTwitterClass : NSObject <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: @user777304 I added a delegate to my answer

Comment: Thats great thanks... I learned it.. But I am talking about framework delegates. like .. - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)mailController didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    NSString *msg1;

Comment: I added an example for adding the `MFMailComposerDelegate` for the custom twitter class and the view controller.

Comment: I tried NSObject.. But getting this error "no visible interface..." on this line... [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil]

Comment: If you are trying to use the `presentViewController:animated` method, the object you are subclassing has to be a `UIViewController`. You can replace `NSObject` with `UIViewController` if you want to, since that would work.

Answer (score 0):

The answers make it more complicated than what it really is:

You need to create  an NSObject Class as above with a mytweet.h and a mytweet.m

In your UIViewController methods you need to instantiate the custom class you created:

```
#import Mytweet.h;
```

....

```
 -(void) viewDidload { ...

    }
```

then invoke the methods as follows:

```
 -(IBACTION) Handletweet{ 

      Mytweet *a = [[Mytweet alloc] init];
      Bool ABC = [Mytweet custom_method1:parameter1 p2:parameter2];}
```

as with anything in Objective C you will need to keep in mind that the objects has a lifetime it get created and released (automatically with ARC) so any parameter that you need to be live beyond the life of your custom class need to be created outside the custom class and passed as a parameter.

```
      Mytweet *a = [[Mytweet alloc] init];
      a.parameter1 = value;
```

where in my tweet.h

```
     @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *parameter1;
```

Re: Delegates - Delegate methods are a way to override the written methods by a calling class, these are typical in Apple or 3rd party framework classes since the entire source may not be open to you, For custom classes, you don't need them just customize and add methods to the custom class as much as you want, you will find this results in cleaner code than otherwise